# Unable to load .so file

Tags: java, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, ubuntu-12.04, shared-objects

I have an application which uses one native library "libSample.so" which is depend upon another .so file.I am trying to load that library using following code

```
File File1 = new File("libSample.so");

static
{
     try {
            System.load(File1.getAbsolutePath());

          } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.out.println("Link Error");
          }

 }
```

Before  loading library I have tried setting up LD_LIBRARY_PATH where  the library is located using command line.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/usb:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

But still the library not get load.
What should I do now?
Please help.

Comment: How are you running your program? are you using an IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ) to do it?

Comment: does libSample comes with additional dependencies?

Comment: @morgano I am using the Eclipse to run my program and I have also tried to setting up LD_LIBRARY_PATH through VM arguments in eclipse.

Comment: @Jayan Yes this library has one dependent .so file.I have kept that dependent .so file with our .so file

Comment: @rachana Why don't you try loadLibrary as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: and the way you setup LD_LIBRARY_PATH in eclipse through VM args is with java.library.path, right?

Comment: Yes.I have set both path the java.library.path as well as the LD_LIBRARY_PATH through VM arguments.And It shows the right path of that location library.

Comment: @ rachana : please post full exception.  That may give some clue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("libSample.so");
}
```

I assumed that you have your jars in /libs directory and .so file in /libs/armeabi directory so the system finds them. You do not have to add .so files in your eclipse build path.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But I have already tried with the System.loadLibrary("libSample.so");but still there is problem in loading library

Comment: Hey I am a novice here. And getting the same problem doing it with OpenCV third party code. Please help with some intuitions

Comment: @MilindJindal If your problem is not solved by this answer, then most probably you have different problem. If you can't find any answer here in SO, please post a question explaining your scenario.